# JSON или MongoDB

Tags: json, сервер, mongodb, gameserver

Делаю сервер для онлайн игры на NodeJS, и мне надо куда либо сохранять такие данные, как: ник игрока, его баланс, пол, внешность, скины которые на нем сейчас, его инвентарь (все скины которые у него есть)

Что мне лучше использовать, базу данных MongoDB или JSON файл хранящийся на сервере и почему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Любая БД будет лучше, так надёжнее и быстрее (их же пишут много профессионалов), масштабируемее (встроенная поддержка асинхронности), а также полезнее в плане опыта.

Помимо MongoDB советую рассмотреть [SQLite](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3) (node-sqlite3) и [NeDB](https://habr.com/ru/post/301916/) (**N**ode.js **E**mbedded **D**ata**B**ase), возможно это будет попроще, т.к они не требуют установки и настройки СУБД, а сами данные тоже пишутся в файл.

Comment: То есть для SQLite и NeDB мне не нужно запускать отдельный сервер?

Comment: @ДаняХелл да, это так называемые встраиваемые СУБД, их применяют во многих небольших приложениях, где надо качественно хранить и обрабатывать данные, а сервер не в тему (например, мобильные приложения).

Answer (score 1):

Надежность, масштабируемость, и т. д. это конечно хорошо, но всего этого можно достичь и с помощью решений для работы с файловой системой, типа простейшего fsync и прочее.
Фишка баз в том что они являются именно что "базами данных", т е "штуками" предназначенными для РАБОТЫ с данными, а не простим их сохранением да дисках/памяти.
Ты сможешь как-то производить поиск по ним, агрегировать, делать аналитические (и не только) выборки по всякиских критериях и прочее, и прочее. И скорее всего это тебе рано или поздно понадобиться, уж поверь ;)
Тем более что mongodb простая как пробка, в любом случае с ней работать проще чем с все теми же разпределенными файловыми хранилиами и прочим.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB будет в разы лучше, т.к. хранить данные пользователей ненадёжно! В случае ошибки записи в файл, все, что было в файле, исчезнет. Я раньше тоже использовал JSON для хранения данных, но понял, что это ненадёжно, и теперь использую MongoDB и не жалуюсь.

Answer (score 0):

Я полностью согласен с первой частью ответа Alster о том что базы данных предназначены для работы с данными (а не только для их хранения) и концовка его ответа на мой взгляд не так однозначна.

Если вы имеете чёткое представление о том, как будет устроена ваша игра в конечном итоге и знаете, что никаких аукционов или статистического анализа в ней не предвидится, а все данные вам нужно обрабатывать лично и не нужно ничего кешировать, то использование базы данных в такой ситуации только ухудшит производительность, читаемость кода и отнимет кучу времени.